# How to get Google Contacts Image link Using Gdata python

Tags: python, gdata, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

How to get Google Contacts Image link Using Gdata python client.

I tried `gd_client.GetPhoto(contact_entry)`, its allows to download the contacts images locally.

But i don't want to save images locally. I need direct image link so that i can populate in my web app dynamically, like `<img src="google contact image link"></img>`.

Any solution is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer [google-api-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) library, OAuth 2.0 authentication and you can get the photo URI from the basic user profile:

[Obtaining User Profile Information](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall)

Here's an example of using some of this with AppEngine:

[Google+ OAuth 2.0 AppEngine Sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg/samples/appengine)